# PHP resorting tr's in a table by class

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a pretty large table which I put on the page with a php call

```
<?php include('7c2dsf12c24-4441e-532ded8-88dsc7-4fsd2c8.txt'); ?>
```

That file has thousands of TR's and TD's within.
The text file is dynamically created and updated every couple of hours.

Some of the rows have a "featuredRow" class on them, which helps with styling.
However, they appear in a random order in that text file.

I need to sort them so that the featured rows go first. Basically take all the rows, and put all the featuredRows at the top of the table, followed by all the other rows.

I already have javascript code that sorts the table by different td's alphabetically, but since its a front-end sorting, and the table consists of thousands of tr's (the text file is 7mb of text), it is quite a strain on Internet Explorer, if I was to filter it initially (the user expects to wait a long time when reordering the entire table alhpabetically, but he is not expected to wait 30 seconds until everything is ordered right (only 2-3 seconds on chrome is 20-30 seconds on IE)).

Therefore I figured that doing it on the backend, and displaying a reordered text file right away would be better, instead of using the dom, to create huge arrays and lag out the user's browser.

TL/DR
As an example, the file's structure looks like something like this:

```
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

I need to take that file and reorder the structure to this:

```
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="featuredRow"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

And I do not want to use JS since there are thousands of rows, megabytes of data, and it will take a long time on IE to do it on the front-end.

What is the easiest way to make it work in PHP?

Thank you

P.S.
Here is how the html/php looks like now - [jsfiddle.net/1pggwuah](http://jsfiddle.net/1pggwuah)

Here is another link on how two trs of the text file look like (there are about 3,000-4,000 of those trs in the text file) [jsfiddle.net/a308w8b6](http://jsfiddle.net/a308w8b6)

Comment: You could use DOM classes to read the html and sort it. An other way of dooing this would be with XSLT.

Comment: Your file contains **only** `<tr>` lines or it is a complete HTML? Also, the example is coherent? In other words, do you have only two kinds of lines (`<tr class="featuredRow">` and `<tr>`)?

Comment: It contains only <tr> lines with tds, text, and stuff WITHIN the tr lines. The table is defined outside of the text file. Yes, there are only two kinds of lines: with the class, and an empty <tr>

Comment: Please check these links for examples 
https://jsfiddle.net/1pggwuah/1/
https://jsfiddle.net/a308w8b6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rows = file_get_contents('/path/to/rows.html');
$rows = explode('<tr', $rows);
sort($rows);
$rows = implode('<tr', $rows);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/bITopF

Comment: you really think sort() can sort by "which lines contain "class="featuredRow"" and keep it inside the <table> tag? lol you gotta be kidding me

Comment: @hanshenrik it's depend. We are waiting OP response. We don't know the file content

Comment: Assuming the sample he is showing is a true sample of the data yes. That is: (1) we have new lines after each tr, (2) there is only trs.

Comment: and assuming sort() ranks spaces higer than > 's , i suppose so, a cool little hack if you're right - edit: haha you're right! (just tested)

Comment: @MajidFouladpour You beat me to it! I'll waiting OP comment to see if this solution is possible. A suggestion: use `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()` .In this case it is faster.

Comment: @fusion3k OP's decision to transfer the responsibility of sorting the rows backend might turn out to be very taxing, it would be wise to go for the least resource-hungry method if data allows it.

Comment: problem: its too taxing for internet explorer. 
solution: make it taxing on the server instead of the user

Comment: @hanshenrik or use the opportunity to persuade users use a better browser instead of paying more $$$ for server RAM/Cores ;)

Comment: with proper caching, i doubt it'd be very taxing on the server anyway. ^^

Comment: @MajidFouladpour I don't know if your solution is less-memory-usage: you load entire file. BTW, I tested it until 200000 lines and it is not a big problem.

Comment: So, OP say YES! +1 by me too

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/..../thephpfile.php on line 82

Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/..../thephpfile.php on line 83

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/..../thephpfile.php on line 84

Comment: Here is another link on how two trs of the text file look like (there are about 3,000-4,000 of those trs in the text file) https://jsfiddle.net/a308w8b6/

The entire file consists only of these trs

Comment: @Romtim the updated script does not assume you have newlines at the end of each row. The warning you show above is unrelated to this though. Please share what exactly you have before lines 82.

Comment: @Romtim the warning has to do with the same unrelated wp stuff; check the demo.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, everything works. Forgot to echo at the end, which resulted in an empty table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile('7c2dsf12c24-4441e-532ded8-88dsc7-4fsd2c8.txt');
$masterele=$domd->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(0);
foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("tr") as $trele){
if($trele->getAttribute("class")!=="featuredRow"){continue;}
$trele->parentNode->removeChild($trele);
$masterele->insertBefore($trele,$masterele->firstChild);
}
echo $domd->saveHTML();
```

EDIT: the original code would put "featuredRow"'s at the bottom, not the top, sorry, fixed it now (use insertBefore instead of append)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I get the following error: function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /home/usxjobs/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/page-template-job-filter.php on line 83

Comment: I have updated the original post with links to examples of the structure in the end of it.